# Express: Command Not Found & Unmet Dependency

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, mean.io

I've looked through many posts and haven't found this specific problem. At this point it's unclear what I have installed/unistalled, but I was hopping that this error message and what follows would shed some light. It's a lot, but I felt more info would be helpful. It's also possible I'm missunderstanding some fundamental concept of express.

```
Machine:~$ npm install express -g
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, unlink '/Users/Machine/.node/lib/node_modules/express/History.md'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/Users/Machine/.node/lib/node_modules/express/History.md']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/Users/Machine/.node/lib/node_modules/express/History.md' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.4.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "express" "-g"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/Machine
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.33
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! path /Users/Machine/.node/lib/node_modules/express/History.md
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, unlink '/Users/Machine/.node/lib/node_modules/express/History.md'
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES, unlink '/Users/Machine/.node/lib/node_modules/express/History.md'
npm ERR! error rolling back  { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/Users/Machine/.node/lib/node_modules/express/History.md']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 3,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/Users/Machine/.node/lib/node_modules/express/History.md' }
npm ERR! not ok code 0
Machine:~$ sudo npm install express -g
Password:
express@4.10.4 /Users/Machine/.node/lib/node_modules/express
├── utils-merge@1.0.0
├── merge-descriptors@0.0.2
├── fresh@0.2.4
├── cookie-signature@1.0.5
├── cookie@0.1.2
├── escape-html@1.0.1
├── range-parser@1.0.2
├── finalhandler@0.3.2
├── vary@1.0.0
├── media-typer@0.3.0
├── parseurl@1.3.0
├── methods@1.1.0
├── serve-static@1.7.1
├── content-disposition@0.5.0
├── path-to-regexp@0.1.3
├── depd@1.0.0
├── qs@2.3.3
├── on-finished@2.1.1 (ee-first@1.1.0)
├── debug@2.1.0 (ms@0.6.2)
├── etag@1.5.1 (crc@3.2.1)
├── proxy-addr@1.0.4 (forwarded@0.1.0, ipaddr.js@0.1.5)
├── send@0.10.1 (destroy@1.0.3, ms@0.6.2, mime@1.2.11)
├── accepts@1.1.3 (negotiator@0.4.9, mime-types@2.0.3)
└── type-is@1.5.3 (mime-types@2.0.3)
Machine:~$ ls
Applications        Movies          bin
Desktop         Music           node_modules
Documents       PdaNetUninstall.sh  package.json
Downloads       Pictures        perl5
Google Drive        Public          routes
Library         app.js          views
Machine:~$ cd Doc*
Machine:Documents$ ls
BDB             Practical Computer Concepts
Molecular Biology
Machine:Documents$ mkdir testFolder
Machine:Documents$ ls
BDB             Practical Computer Concepts
Molecular Biology       testFolder
Machine:Documents$ cd test*
Machine:testFolder$ ls
Machine:testFolder$ express mytestapp
-bash: express: command not found
Machine:testFolder$
```

As you can see, I've tried several different methods of installing experss, from using -g, to the npm install express-generator etc. Nothing has worked.

Of additional interest, when I run look at all the npm packages I have I this:

```
Machine:TestApp$ npm list
Machine@0.0.0 /Users/Machine
├── UNMET DEPENDENCY body-parser@~1.8.1
├── UNMET DEPENDENCY cookie-parser@~1.3.3
├── UNMET DEPENDENCY debug@~2.0.0
├─┬ express@4.9.8
│ ├─┬ accepts@1.1.3
│ │ ├─┬ mime-types@2.0.3
│ │ │ └── mime-db@1.2.0
│ │ └── negotiator@0.4.9
│ ├── cookie@0.1.2
│ ├── cookie-signature@1.0.5
│ ├─┬ debug@2.0.0
│ │ └── ms@0.6.2
│ ├── depd@0.4.5
│ ├── escape-html@1.0.1
│ ├─┬ etag@1.4.0
│ │ └── crc@3.0.0
│ ├── finalhandler@0.2.0
│ ├── fresh@0.2.4
│ ├── media-typer@0.3.0
│ ├── merge-descriptors@0.0.2
│ ├── methods@1.1.0
│ ├─┬ on-finished@2.1.1
│ │ └── ee-first@1.1.0
│ ├── parseurl@1.3.0
│ ├── path-to-regexp@0.1.3
│ ├─┬ proxy-addr@1.0.4
│ │ ├── forwarded@0.1.0
│ │ └── ipaddr.js@0.1.5
│ ├── qs@2.2.4
│ ├── range-parser@1.0.2
│ ├─┬ send@0.9.3
│ │ ├── destroy@1.0.3
│ │ ├── mime@1.2.11
│ │ ├── ms@0.6.2
│ │ └─┬ on-finished@2.1.0
│ │   └── ee-first@1.0.5
│ ├── serve-static@1.6.4
│ ├─┬ type-is@1.5.3
│ │ └─┬ mime-types@2.0.3
│ │   └── mime-db@1.2.0
│ ├── utils-merge@1.0.0
│ └── vary@1.0.0
├── UNMET DEPENDENCY jade@~1.6.0
├── UNMET DEPENDENCY morgan@~1.3.0
└── UNMET DEPENDENCY serve-favicon@~2.1.3

npm ERR! missing: body-parser@~1.8.1, required by Machine@0.0.0
npm ERR! missing: cookie-parser@~1.3.3, required by Machine@0.0.0
npm ERR! missing: morgan@~1.3.0, required by Machine@0.0.0
npm ERR! missing: serve-favicon@~2.1.3, required by Machine@0.0.0
npm ERR! missing: debug@~2.0.0, required by Machine@0.0.0
npm ERR! missing: jade@~1.6.0, required by Machine@0.0.0
npm ERR! not ok code 0
Machine:TestApp$ express -h
-bash: express: command not found
Machine:TestApp$ npm cache clean
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, unlink '/Users/Machine/.npm/abbrev/1.0.5'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/Users/Machine/.npm/abbrev/1.0.5']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/Users/Machine/.npm/abbrev/1.0.5' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.4.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "cache" "clean"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/Machine/Documents/BDB/Final Project/TestApp
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.33
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! path /Users/Machine/.npm/abbrev/1.0.5
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, unlink '/Users/Machine/.npm/abbrev/1.0.5'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Machine/Documents/BDB/Final Project/TestApp/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

These steps will clean out any cruft that might be causing the issue and let you start as fresh as possible.  I use a variants on this approach when I'm running into the same mysterious "it *should* work" situations with `npm` as you are seeing...

1. `sudo npm rm express -g` to get rid of the global install...we're going to start fresh
2. `sudo npm cache clean` to ... clean the cache.  it's the 'turn it off and on again' of node
3. `sudo npm install express -g` to start new

*Side note:* It is good practice to move the npm global installation directory to a place that won't require `sudo`.  You can find several articles on how to do this both here on StackOverflow as well as via search engines...